# select inside select doesn't work in hive

Tags: sql, hive, hiveql

**The next query would work in oracle, but not in hive:**

```
select user_key,(sum(333)/(select 10 from table.dual)) calculationResult from user_usage_table group by user_key;
```

**The result I expect:**

```
user_key    calculationResult
DB-_app6_61_28fba6e2f0_12d  2930.4
DB-_app6_61_28fba6e2f0_171  2930.4
DB-_app6_61_28fba6e2f0_1b5  2930.4
DB-_app6_61_28fba6e2f0_69   2930.4
DB-_app6_61_28fba6e2f0_e9   2930.4
```

**what do I get:**

```
FAILED: ParseException line 1:33 cannot recognize input near 'select' '10' 'from' in expression specification
```

How do I apply this in hive?

Answer (score 1):

Your query is quite strange.  Why not just write:

```
select user_key, (sum(333) / 10) as calculationResult
from user_usage_table
group by user_key;
```

This should work in both Oracle and hive.

Comment: I just gave a more simple example. I need this second 'select' for a calculation that uses some different fields.

Comment: @JacobRoginsky . . . You provided a query and an error, but the two don't match?